# How do I match values in columns of two different tables to extract corresponding values in a different column of the second table in R?

Tags: r

I understand this is a basic thing and definitely has already been asked but I can't find something that fits what I'm looking for and I'm a bit rusty in R.

I have a table called `snpMap` which contains both two sets of genomic coordinates, one old and another new. I have an output table that has accidentally been encoded in the old genomic coordinate format called `bim`. What I want to do is match the columns between the two different tables based on their common "old" genomic coordinate columns and then extract the "new" genomic coordinates from `snpMap` and place them into new columns in their corresponding rows in `bim`. I understand this is like using a lookup table and it's something I've even done before but like I said, I'm a little rusty.

Because the genomic coordinates are broken up into separate columns e.g. chromosome and coordinate, I concatenated them in both tables to make the process a bit easier:

```
snpMap$hg19_coords <- with(snpMap, paste0("chr", CHR, "-", POS))
snpMap$hg38_coords <- with(snpMap, paste0(chr_hg38, "-", pos_hg38))

bim$hg19_coords <- with(bim, paste0("chr", chr, "-", basepair))
```

where `hg19` is old and `hg38` is new. Below is the reference table, `snpMap`:

```
                       CHR                    SNP CM    POS COUNTED ALT Type
rs4951929:757734:C:T     1   rs4951929:757734:C:T  0 757734       C   T  SNV
rs4951862:757936:C:A     1   rs4951862:757936:C:A  0 757936       C   A  SNV
rs3131954:758626:C:T     1   rs3131954:758626:C:T  0 758626       C   T  SNV
rs114111569:759837:T:A   1 rs114111569:759837:T:A  0 759837       T   A  SNV
rs112618790:777232:C:T   1 rs112618790:777232:C:T  0 777232       T   C  SNV
rs4040617                1              rs4040617  0 779322       G   A  SNV
                       newRef newCount        name  rsNumGuess chr_hg38
rs4951929:757734:C:T        T        C   rs4951929   rs4951929     chr1
rs4951862:757936:C:A        A        C   rs4951862   rs4951862     chr1
rs3131954:758626:C:T        T        C   rs3131954   rs3131954     chr1
rs114111569:759837:T:A      A        T rs114111569 rs114111569     chr1
rs112618790:777232:C:T      C        T rs112618790 rs112618790     chr1
rs4040617                   A        G   rs4040617   rs4040617     chr1
                       pos_hg38 hg19_coords hg38_coords
rs4951929:757734:C:T     822354 chr1-757734 chr1-822354
rs4951862:757936:C:A     822556 chr1-757936 chr1-822556
rs3131954:758626:C:T     823246 chr1-758626 chr1-823246
rs114111569:759837:T:A   824457 chr1-759837 chr1-824457
rs112618790:777232:C:T   841852 chr1-777232 chr1-841852
rs4040617                843942 chr1-779322 chr1-843942
```

The old coordinates are `CHR` and `POS` (which I've concatenated into `hg19_coords`) and the new ones are `chr_hg38` and `pos_hg38` (which I've also concatenated into `hg38_coords`).

Below is the output table, `bim`:

```
> head(bim)
   chr                    snp position basepair allele1 allele2 hg19_coords
1:   1   rs4951929:757734:C:T        0   757734       C       T chr1-757734
2:   1   rs4951862:757936:C:A        0   757936       C       A chr1-757936
3:   1   rs3131954:758626:C:T        0   758626       C       T chr1-758626
4:   1 rs114111569:759837:T:A        0   759837       T       A chr1-759837
5:   1 rs112618790:777232:C:T        0   777232       T       C chr1-777232
6:   1              rs4040617        0   779322       G       A chr1-779322
```

I want to replace the columns `chr` and `basepair` with the corresponding `hg38` values using `hg19_coords` as a "key". Ultimately, I want to replace the values in `snp` too but that's a different ballgame.

How should I approach this? This is all with `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an inelegant solution, but here it is:

```
bimjoin <- bim %>%
    left_join(snpMap, by = "hg19_coords") %>%
    subset(., select = c("chr_hg38", "snp", "position", "pos_hg38", "allele1", "allele2"))
```